# After upgrading constraint layout library to 2.0.2 app crashes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Steps to reproduce:

1. I upgraded constraint layout version to 2.0.2.

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
   ```
2. When I open fragment which uses constraint layout app crashes with the exception

   ```
   2020-10-22 17:13:33.425 19010-19010/com.onoff24.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.onoff24.android, PID: 19010
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 
   'androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene$Transition androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene.mCurrentTransition' on a null object reference
   at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onAttachedToWindow(MotionLayout.java:3486)
   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5278)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.addView(FragmentContainerView.java:280)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:326)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

So I downgraded the version to 2.0.1 and it works fine.

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
```